# Reading and visualizing quotation marks in d3.js from a CSV

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3.js for visualizing the following CSV file (example):

```
special character,count
@,1276
",1262
.,830
#,78
```

unfortunatelly, when reading the quotation marks ("), d3's csv parser (I am using the d3.csv function) can not correctly interpret them. I have limited experience with Javascript, but I think the issue is the character's parsing by Javascript itself.

Even when pinting the character on-screen with:

```
alert(d["special character"]);
```

I find that all special characters (@,!,/, etc) are printed correctly, but when finding '"', the following would appear with the example:

```
,1262
.,830
#,788
```

as if upon finding the quotes, the csv parser can not understand them as a character and gets all the following content as one csv element.

I have tried escaping / unescaping the character, various encodings with conditionals, with no success. I have also tried using d3.dsv, which allows to specify the csv separator.

```
d3.dsv(fieldSeparator, "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

Has anyone found the same issue before?

thanks for reading!

Comment: You need to escape the quote character, otherwise the file isn't valid CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure to escape your double quote with a double quote?

```
special character,count
@,1276
"",1262
.,830
#,78
```

Comment: Escaping the quotation marks via "", I don't get an error, but the quotation marks are not visible on the graph :/

Comment: Try prepending \ after parsing.